# How to pass array from view controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i make table in blade.php, and i want to pass array value to controller, here is my blade.php

```
@foreach ($alats as $data)
<tr>
        <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 3px solid {{$warna}}">{{$no}}</td>
        <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 3px solid {{$warna}}" name="no_inventaris[]">{{$data->no_inventaris}}</td>
        <td align="center"  style="border-bottom: 3px solid {{$warna}}" name="kode_alat[]">{{$data->kode_alat}}</td>
        <td align="center"  style="border-bottom: 3px solid {{$warna}}" name="tahun[]">{{$data->tahun}}</td>
        <td align="center"  style="border-bottom: 3px solid {{$warna}}" name="jenis_alat[]">{{$data->jenis_alat}}</td>
        <td align="center"  style="border-bottom: 3px solid {{$warna}}" name="merk_alat[]">{{$data->merk_alat}}</td>
        <td align="center"  style="border-bottom: 3px solid {{$warna}}" name="tipe_alat[]">{{$data->tipe_alat}}</td>
    </tr>
```

and i want to pass no_inventaris value to controller

```
public function kirimsemua(Request $request){
        $namas = $request->nama;
        $ids = $request->no_inventaris->get();

        $get_alat = Alat::whereIn('no_inventaris',$ids)->get();

        $permohonan[] = new Permohonan;
        foreach ($get_alat as $key) {
            $permohonan = new Permohonan;
            $permohonan->no_inventaris = $ids;
            $permohonan->tanggal_permohonan = date("Y-m-d");
            $permohonan->tindakan = "";
            $permohonan->nama_pengirim = $request->nama;
            $permohonan->kode_lokasi = $get_alat->kode_lokasi;
            $permohonan->id_workcenter = $get_alat->id_workcenter;
            $permohonan->alasan = $request->input_alasan;
            $permohonan->save();
        }

        DB::table('q_alat')->whereIn('no_inventaris', $ids)
        ->update(['status' => 'terkirim']);

        return redirect('request_kalibrasi_user/'.$namas)->with('sort',"1");
}
```

but it always gets error

> Call to a member function get() on null

Comment: that isnt a form with inputs? how are sending data with the request?

Comment: Even if you are send the post data via ajax - because otherwise you would require form with input elements - you should check `dd($request->input('no_inventaris'))` within your controller method. If it's an array then you can use array index to fetch values. I don't think ['a', 'r', 'r']->get() exists - `get()` on array probably doesn't exist

Comment: i want to get the data from another table on database and then save it to another table, that''s why i don't have form with inputs

Answer (score 0):

Use `$request->get()` method.

```php
$namas = $request->get('namas');
$noInventarisIds = $request->get('no_inventaris');

// ...
```

Comment: i tried to do this, it doesn't error but it didn't save the data to database

Comment: I had fixed your problem. And about not saving to DB, you need to check your input and debug the updating query.